# Future.get() returning results long after its available in java 8

Tags: java, tomcat, parallel-processing, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I am using an executor inside a webapplication running in tomcat. Each request that arrives at tomcat, submits a new job to a singleton ExecutorService. The ExecutorService is configured with 12 threads, which is same as number of CPUs available. Around 60 concurrent requests, i notice that there is significant difference between when the job finished within Callable as compared to when results are available via Future.get(). Below pseudo code shows the use case.

I have a Callable such as

```java
public class DoSomething implements Callable<long> {


  public long call() {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    //do some cpu intensive task
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("time taken: " + (end-start));
    return end-start;
  }
}
```

When i pass the above Callable to ExecutorService such as

```
  long realStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
  ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(12);
  Future<DoSomething> x = service.submit(new DoSomething());
  long y = x.get();
  long realEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
  long realTimeTaken = realEnd - realStart;
```

What i have observed is that the time taken within DoSomething is like 40ms, where-as realTimeTaken is as long as 500ms.

Comment: `ExecutorService.fixedThreadPool()` - is that a method that actually exists?

Comment: Could it be you are misinterpreting the results? If DoSomething takes 40ms  and realTimeTaken 500ms, my guess would be that the first 460ms are spent waiting for a thread to become free, after which it executes for 40ms and returns the result -- not that it executes 40ms and then waits before returning the result.

Comment: Also: multithreading different servlet requests should probably be configured with tomcat, not implemented manually.

Comment: @immibis no sorry, that was quick typo. fixed it

Comment: Are all your tasks running on the same executor? (They should be)

Comment: @immibis i am running them on 2 executors. one for blocking IO and other for cpu intensive tasks.

Comment: Okay, the code you posted looks like it creates a pool with 12 threads and then submits only one task, if you're wondering why I asked.

Comment: @AdrianLeonhard You could be right. I need to check on it. Besides now it makes more sense. If the task is waiting for 460ms, i can probably benefit by increasing the thread count a bit, as long as i dont max all CPU Cores

Comment: Use System.nanoTime() not millis. Millis is very inaccurate and is not for timing anything.